# a5paper b5paper with report class in pdf by pdflatex?

Tags: pdf, paper-size

Selection of paper size within `report` class, changes rendering.

However pdf pages remains bigger.

How to make pdf made with `pdflatex` to be a5,b5 ?

Example:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}`.

Comment: Now pdf page has proper size :)